# Integral and Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Could an integral whose both limits, or one, are infinite be optimized using the Euler-Lagrange equation? (Any resource on the matter is appreciated)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathcal{L}(x,f(x),f'(x))\,dx$$

Comment: Yea the limits of the integral shouldn’t matter if they are constant (in this case constant to infinity). If the limits themselves are functions then stuff can sometimes get weird.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Any academic reference for this please? The courses I found online describe the equation for a Lagrangian defined on [a,b] not R or maybe [a, +inf[.

Comment: I don’t have An academic reference here. The thing that’s important is to realize the Euler Lagrange equations don’t depend on the endpoints of integration at all in their derivation. The ELE looks the same regardless what constants are in the endpoints of the integral.